# Regex for matching 4 words within 20 words distance in a text

Tags: regex, string, pattern-matching

I'm trying to create a regular expression which can match 4 words in a text within 20 word distance and they also should be in order

For 2 words within 10 words range I could use the below

```
"\b(?:word1\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,10}?word2"
```

But unable to get for matching 4 words, so looking for suggestions.

Example:

sample,regular, validation, transformation - These 4 words should be present within 20 words in the below text

*This is a sample regular expression text. Regular expression is used for string validation, parsing and transformation.The term "Regular expression" is typically abbreviated as "RegEx" or "regex".*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want up to 20 words in between first and last word which makes 22 total.

What you could do, is to check if the first and last word are within the desired words distance and use a [lookahead `(?=...)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) after the first word to check for the two middle words in desired order while not skipping the last word by use of negative lookaheads `(?!...)`.

```
/\b(sample)\W+                         # first word (group 1)
  (?=                                  # look ahead
    (?:(?!(?4))\w+\W+)*?(regular)\W+   # for word 2 (group 2)
    (?:(?!(?4))\w+\W+)*?(validation)   # for word 3 (group 3)
  )                                    # eof lookahead
(?:\w+\W+){0,20}?(transformation\b)    # last word (group 4)
/ix
```

In [this pcre demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zxD6pj/4) I put some [capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for highlighting the matched words and used a [pattern reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) `(?4)` to the last word pattern for making the regex shorter.

Used the [flags](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `i (case insensitive)`, `x (free spacing/comment mode)`

You can improve performance by [dropping the capturing groups and reference](https://regex101.com/r/zxD6pj/3). Just dropping the reference would also make the pattern more compatible to other regex flavors like Javascript.

---

If you're using PHP and just want to check if the 4 words are in order within desired range you could also use a more simple regex and count the words with `str_word_count()`.

```
$pattern = '/\bsample\b.*?\bregular\b.*?\bvalidation\b.*?\btransformation\b/is';

if(preg_match($pattern, $str, $out) && (str_word_count($out[0]) <= 22))
{ /* do something */ }
```

[See this php demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/1042245)

Comment: thank you so much for the solution. It does solve my problem to an extent and also helps me in understanding on how to approach such problems.